# C# calls go function within dll, and it's running in .Net Core, will the unmanaged memory allocated by go gets Garbage Collected?

Tags: c#, go, .net-core, garbage-collection

I write a file transfer interface in Go which accepts localpath and remote server information, then transfer the file by chunk. The situation is that I want to use it in C#, and I get to know Go can be built into **C-Shared dll and called in C# with P/Invoke**. I want to know if the unmanaged memory allocated by go will be **garbage collected**? If not, is there a way to release these part of memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The garbage collector won't have knowledge of the unmanaged memory of the Go code.

If you want to release it you should manage it in the Go code, or at least prepare a function to be called in C# and Dispose the unmanaged memory.

My advise would be:

- Function in Go that releases memory
- Then call this function in C# when you want to dispose the object.

Comment: Did it worked for you? Remember to accept the answer if it worked.

Comment: sorry, I still have some questions:since golang is garbaged collected so it has no func to release it's own memory like a slice or a byte array, how will these memory go? So I have no way to call funcs to release go memory in C#.

Comment: When you pass a managed type, golang will handle it. Usually, managed languages sends a copy of the value if you export the function (like you are doing to C#).

But in your case I think that it is different because you are sending a stream of bytes of a file to C#. If you open a stream you should be able to close it aswell.